# NetBios lookup from command line/powershell in Vista

Tags: windows, netbios, powershell-2.0

Am trying to resolve an IP address to its Netbios name via the command line or via powershell.  the system I am using is Vista SP2 so I do not believe NBLookup.exe will work.  are there any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

View the netbios table per connection by executing the following on the command line or in powershell. Do mind that `-A` is case sensitive. `-A` resolves IP to name, `-a` resolves name to IP.

```
nbtstat -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  looking at my command history i have been using nbstat rather than nbtstat.  just assumed it had been removed from vista!  Thanks for the swift response

Comment: @TimAlexander You're very welcome!